# SIP Publish event

Tags: events, sip, publish

I'm a newbie for SIP.

I would like to send the whole address book of a registered SIP user using a SIP message (**PUBLISH**)

I do not understand the event package that I should use.

--> [Event Package List](http://www.iana.org/assignments/sip-events/sip-events.xhtml)

Can anyone help me?

Riccardo

NB: I'm writing the AS which will handle the SIP messages...

Comment: Please elaborate the use case. You would normally do it the other way, SUBSCRIBE to a resource (contact) list for a specific set of information items, for example presence. Who would be the receiver of this PUBLISH message and what should the result be of the processing of that message?

Comment: I'm developing an app which must send to my SIP Application Server the user contact list and others data. I was thinking to make a publish to AS in order to send this data.

Comment: For contact lits i mean the address book

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any standardized event package for this purpose. SIP PUBLISH is normally used to publish event state (like presence or dialog state) to an entity that in turn composes that state  and possibly maintains subscriptions to it from other entities.

Is it necessary to use SIP for this purpose? SIP is not really meant to be a content delivery protocol. It sounds more like a job for HTTP or WebDAV to me.

Comment: We need to use SIP. Now I'm trying to use or a custom event or extend body of presence-event

Comment: Well, it still sounds like an odd job for PUBLISH. The stuff you PUBLISH is meant to have a limited lifetime, and needs to be refreshed ever so often and etags should also be maintained (if you do it by the book). What is the AS going to do with the contacts?

Comment: I'm writing also the AS and saving the publish into a database